# About sample code in book 'Data science with Dask and python'

Tags: python, dask

I am currently reading the book 'Data science with Dask and python'
And in chapter 05,  the sample code

```
with ProgressBar():
    nyc_data_stage4.isnull().sum().compute()
```

gives such error
`TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'`

And I check a little bit further

```
nyc_data_clean_stage3 = nyc_data_clean_stage2.dropna(subset=rows_to_drop)
nyc_data_clean_stage4 = nyc_data_clean_stage3.fillna(unknown_default_dict)
```

It seems like it is because the dropna method got a default kwarg how='any' that yields this problem,
any idea how to fix it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: can't you use other value for `how=` ? Check in documentation what values you could use.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and the code is working fine if you include only up to 9 variables in the "rows_to_drop" list. As soon as you increase it to above 9, it suddenly throws this error. Don't know what is the problem here.